# Simple IPv4 and port validation for chat client

Tags: c#, validation, networking, client

This is part of my chat client's code.  It works fine but it looks messy.  Any ideas?

```
//IP Validation
private void textBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    bool ValidateIP = IPAddress.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out ip);
    if (ValidateIP)
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Disables buttons and locks into text box
        textBox3.Text = "Invalid IPv4 address!!";
        textBox3.Select();
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }
}

//Port Validation
private void textBox4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool ValidatePort;
    int porttest = 0;
    try
    {
        porttest = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {           
    }

    if (porttest > 1 && porttest < 65535)
    {
        ValidatePort = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ValidatePort = false;
    }

    if (ValidatePort)
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Disables buttons and locks into text box
        textBox4.Text = "Invalid Port";
        textBox4.Select();
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Naming

By convention, variables local to a method should be camelCased. You seem to have a mixture of PascalCased and alllowercase, making it hard to see at a glance what a variable is. All lower case has the additional disadvantage of being hard to read.

Your boolean check variables also seem to be named in the form 'VerbNoun'. This is rather confusing because it's usually how methods are named. It sounds like they're supposed to do something. `ValidatePort` for example sounds like something that validates a port. A name like `portValid` or perhaps `isPortValid` more clearly states what the variables are.

### Extracting methods

Looking at both of your methods, they have the same structure: Check if something is valid, if it is then change the state of the form one way, if it isn't then change the state of the form a different way. Each of those are basically completely separate pieces of functionality, so I'd suggest separating them out. This would turn `textBox3_Leave`, for example, into:

```
private void textBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool ipValid = ValidateIP(textbox3.Text);
   if(ipValid)
       EnableControls();
    else
       DisableControls();
}
```

Here the new methods `ValidateIP`, `EnableControls` and `DisableControls` would be private methods containing the bits of code they replace.

This method now immediately states what it is doing: it's validating the text in `textbox3`as an IP, if it's valid then enable the controls, otherwise disable them. Potentially you could get rid of `ipValid` and just put that `ValidateIP` call directly into the `if` statement, it's up to you what you think reads better. You may also be able to improve on those names a bit (enable *which* controls, for example).

### Repetition

Now look at the second method. You'll see that `EnableControls` can be used here too. This means that just by making the first method a clearer statement of what it's doing, we've discovered a valuable *abstraction*, and we no longer have to repeat that enabling controls means enabling `button2` and `button3`.

We can almost use `DisableControls` too, but there's a slight difference- the messages. So to fix that, `DisableControls` should take the message as a string parameter:

```
private void DisableControls(string message);
```

### Integer parsing

It's generally considered bad to use exceptions in normal control flow. That's what you're doing here when you try to check whether the text in `textbox4` is a valid integer or not.

An alternative, which you may not have known about, is `Int32.TryParse`. This method is designed for this exact situation- where you want to check whether a string represents an integer, but don't want to throw an exception if it isn't. This allows you to get rid of that `try...catch` and clean that bit of code up a bit.

### Simplifying `if` statements

If you ever have an `if` statement which reads:

```
if(condition)
{
    value = true;
}
else
{
    value = false;
}
```

You should simplify this to:

```
value = condition;
```

In your case, you can do:

```
ValidatePort = porttest > 1 && porttest < 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Ben said and:

You should give your UI controls sensible names if you access them in code. Right no no-one has any idea what specific functions for example `button2` and `button3` are assigned to do and it's easy to introduce bugs by using them wrong.

In the long run you probably want to check out better designs like [Model-View-Presenter (MVP) or Model-View-Controller (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) to decouple your UI from your logic.

Comment: i use "button2" as default,i should know better,but its to easy to fugue out what they do in VS,but if i copy the code to a forum nobody will know what I'm talking about plus it makes it easy for the code to be reusable by newbees like myself.